# How to move different types of files to a different directory in shell

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have a mix of different files in my folder and I thought I can simply do:

```
mv '*.(png|jpg|gif)' images/
```

to have them moved to the image folder. But it doesn't work... any thoughts?

Comment: I think your error is simply that you have single quotes around the file matching pattern. You will need double quotes, or no quotes at all, in order to use glob expansion.

Answer (score 4):

Use a feature in bash called [brace expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html)

```
mv *.{png,gif,jpg} images
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mv *.png *.jpg *.gif images/
```

should do it

Answer (score 1):

And what shell are you using?

[Goxu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772664/goxu) has the correct answer. There's no reason you should do something more esoteric if you can do it in a more simple and understandable manner.

In the end, the shell expands the command to include all the files before passing the list to the `mv` command, so there's really no performance gain or loss by doing it differently.

However, if you want to be [Mister Fancy Pants](http://www.jonathancoulton.com/2006/08/11/thing-a-week-45-mr-fancy-pants/), you should know that both Bash and Kornshell (both available on OS X) can do the following using extended glob expressions:

```
$ mv *(*.png|*.jpg|*.gif) images
```

Extended glob expressions (aka pattern matching) is really helpful when you want to remove everything from a directory except for one file. For example, you expanded a tar archive, and want to delete all the files except for the tar archive:

```
$ rm -rf !(foo.tar.gz)
```

The thing with Bash is that you have to turn on this functionality via the [shopt](http://www.jonathancoulton.com/2006/08/11/thing-a-week-45-mr-fancy-pants/) command first:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
```

Take a look at the Bash manpage and look at the section on *Pattern Matching*. It contains a lot of neat shell tricks that not too many people know about. It gives your shell some secret super powers, but always remember to use those powers to help mankind and never for evil.

Comment: `*.@(png|jpg|gif)` is a bit simpler. *zsh* also supports these *ksh* patterns with its KSH_GLOB option, and/or its own equivalents with its EXTENDED_GLOB option (`*.(png|jpg|gif)`).